# File.exists() security exception

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, java-io

I'm trying to write an applet for a website that needs access to a system on the LAN, so using a network path (\\THEBOX\DIR\SUBDIR).  I'm checking if the directory exists before using it:

```
try {
    File theDir = new File(filepath);
    if (!theDir.exists()) theDir.mkdir();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getCause()+"\n\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

This catches the exception java.io.FilePermission.  The .jar file is signed with a self certificate.  Here's the catch- if I run this inside of void init() it works fine, but when I name it void myFunction() the error shows.  I need to name it something other than init so it doesn't run on page load and can be called from javascript.

Edit:
As a workaround I'm going to switch back to using init(), but not load the applet until the button is clicked.  While I'd prefer the more proper way we can't always be that fortunate.

Comment: I suspect it's the 'called from Javascript' part that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'll have to think of a workaround.  Thanks for at least some sort of explanation.

Comment: Effective duplicate of [Applet URLConnection.connect fails after being called from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121944/applet-urlconnection-connect-fails-after-being-called-from-javascript)